# BroadcastReceiver and/or AlarmManager do not work when app is closed

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a static inner class that extends Broadcast Receiver; it's called by AlarmManager's object from the same class that contains the inner class. I made minor changes on the project, and somehow the broadcast receiver and alarm manager stop working only when the app is closed even though their logic almost have remained the same.
Here's is the code:

// NotificationManagement class that set ups AlarmManager timing and contain the inner class.

```
public class NotificationManagement {

    private int timerID; // each notification needs a unique integer identifier.
    private Calendar dateTime; // the time and date of the notification.
    private boolean isNotify; // to distinquish between notifying and alarming.

    public NotificationManagement(AssignmentEntity assignment) {
        this.timerID = assignment.getAssignmentID() * -1;
        this.dateTime = getNotifyTime(assignment);
        isNotify = true;
    }


    public void setNotify(Context context) {
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        alarmIntent.putExtra("notifyID", timerID);
        alarmIntent.putExtra("isNotify", isNotify);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, timerID,  alarmIntent, 0);
        System.out.println(timerID + " the dateTime is " + dateTime);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, dateTime.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }

    public static class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
               System.out.println("in receiver");
               // push a notification code.
    }
}
```

Here's how I use NotificationManagement class inside an activity class

```
 private void createNotification(AssignmentEntity assignment) {
        NotificationManagement alarm = new NotificationManagement(assignment);
        alarm.setNotify(this);
    }
```

here's how I declare the receiver in mainfiest between application tags

```
<receiver android:name=".view.NotificationManagement$AlarmReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```